# Adding new PC inside my home network between router and internet source

Tags: router, home-networking, switch

schema of my current network in home looks like on picture below: 
[image: home network]

basically the issue is that I have router & switch in whole other part of the home that I need to add new PC (node) in network,  I could buy another switch and put switch in between antenna and new pc (pink dot) and then that pc would have access to internet, but would it get access to my home NAS which is connected to switch which is behind router?

also I cannot move my router from current location to pink point location because wifi is needed with good quality at its current position - walls are pretty thick, and I have a lot of devices in need of wifi there, like other pcs, tvs, printers etc

what would you suggest as most cost effective way into connecting the pink pc so that it has access to external internet & my current home local network devices? by cost effective I don't explicitly mean 'give me hardware vendors & models' but more like 'you should buy switch and place it in x or buy router and place it in y'

Comment: This will be similar to the 2nd half of https://superuser.com/questions/1482595/does-this-home-network-work-using-an-ethernet-splitter/1482600...

Comment: Have you considered PowerLine adapters, which transfers data over the existing electrical wires in the home _(provided the PC and router are plugged into outlets that share the same electrical panel)_?  The other option would be running CAT6 cable through the PC's wall, into the basement/attic, then into the router's wall, terminating the cable in each wall with a CAT6 keystone jack and plate _([MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/) is one of the best places for those supplies, as they lifetime warranty all their cables)_.

Comment: Put a main router at the entry point. Then put a wireless access point in place of the wireless router in the blue circle. Then you can hook up the pink PC with Ethernet or add a second wireless access point at the pink PC.